# How to Create Multiple Instances of Angular Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

I have an app with the following basic structure,

```
weatherDisplayController.js
  weatherGrabbingService.js
  userColorPreferencesService.js
```

When the user changes their color preferences for viewing the weather, it is stored in       `userColorPreferencesService.js.`

However, I want to add another view where you can view all your friends' dashboards, which means creating a new micro-instance of the module. However, when I do, they will overwrite the color preferences in the Service.

How can I have multiple instances of the same module on one page?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the services are singletons. there's is only 1 existing instance of it.

Maybe make the constructor within your colorservice as a oop class and store multiple of them in the service itself.

```
function ColorPreferences(){
  //any data
} 

app.service("userColorPreferencesService", function(){
  this.ownColors = new ColorPreferences({ /* data goes here */});
  this.buddyColors = [];
});

//in your controller, when sharing actived
userColorPreferencesService.buddyColor = new ColorPreferences({ /* data from ajax? */});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only varying data should be on the scope for that part of the page.  Instead of storing the data in the service you could store it in each scope and pass the required data to the service.